# How to get rid of grey area after gnome-screenshot being executed

Tags: gnome, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Right after I make a screenshot using `gnome-screenshot` some grey rectangle stays on the screen indicating the screenshot area.

In order to remove it, I need to close the gnome-screenshot window **manually**.

The worst part is that those rectangles are:

- layering and placed above all screen windows,
- making the whole interface darker,
- **spoiling** all other screenshots over this area.

See the picture after three screenshots taken around the same white area:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ6LF.png).

Could anyone tell, how to get rid of this areas?
Is it possible?
(Since closing gnome-screenshot windows manually each time is a little bit annoying. I want to make a thousand of pictures and then close all the screenshot windows with two clicks in a taskbar/launcher.)

NB: I know about Shutter and other screenshot programs. The question is about gnome-screenshot in latest Ubuntus, like 16.10, 16.04.

Comment: In my experience, grey rectangle remains if gnome screenshot window is still open, it can happen that the popup produced by it is placed below other windows. Closing the window makes it go away.

Comment: Yes, of course, it disappears after closing the window. The question is how to make it not to appear even if the window is opened. This is how `gnome-screenshot` behaved in earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: And sometimes something goes wrong with gnome-screenshot, and it just never goes away, even though the window is closed.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and changing permissions of ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel fixed it for me.

```
sudo chown user:user ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Replace 'user:user' with your username of course.

Comment: I already have `<user>:<user>` in owner:group and `600` in permission mode. Grey area is present anyway :-(

Comment: Yay! How on earth did you figure that out, Adam?

Comment: `ps aux | grep gnome-screenshot` shows a list of the litte grey squares, and you can `kill` them :)

Comment: The thing is — as I mentioned in the starting topic — I do not want to kill or close `gnome-screenshot`. This is very inconvenient, when you grab a lot of screenshots: closing the screenshoter window every time you make a screenshot. I just want it not to leave any traces on my screen.

Comment: This interferes with the 'by design' behavior that clipboard data is destroyed if the clipboard owner (gnome-screenshot) is closed. Meaning every time I make a screenshot I first have to copy/paste it to another application before I can take another screenshot. The interference between these two behaviors is highly frustrating.

Comment: This has no effect for me, and I'm wondering why it would have any effect at all... still searching for a solution to this :(