# Screen brightness decreases with several gnome-screenshot instances open

Tags: gnome, brightness, screenshot

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have an issue with gnome screenshot (3.18.0).
If I take several screenshots without closing previous screenshot instances, I get progressively less bright images. I hope I help you understanding by posting the pictures of an empty libreoffice page. The first screenshot has the right brightness.
[image: First screenshot, one gnome screenshot instance active]
I then paste the third screenshot (meaning that three instances of gnome screenshot are open at the same time), in which the image is visibly darker.
[image: Third screenshot, three screenshot instances active].
Even worse when the open instances are four.
[image: Four instances]
I do not post more pictures, but the darkening is gradual and apparently continuous, although I never went on to have more than six instances open at the same time.
If I close all the instances of gnome screenshot and take a new screenshot, the brightness is back to normality. 
[image]
Thus, what I usually do is closing screenshot everytime, which is not a big deal, but I am wondering why is this happening. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-screenshot` marks the photographed area by making it slightly darker. That is why your whole screen turns darker after each use without closing the gnome-screenshot window. You can see this effect, if you are screenshotting single non-maximized windows using Alt + Print. The window area will become darker. You can see this more easily when moving other windows around or bringing them to the front.

I do not know of a configuration option to fix this annoyance, so your workaround is the only solution. As an alternative, you can use GIMP for taking screenshots.

Related question: [How to get rid of grey area after gnome screenshot being executed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873813/how-to-get-rid-of-grey-area-after-gnome-screenshot-being-executed).

Comment: It's a huge annoyance, especially when it affects subsequent screenshots!