# gnome-screenshot - Vertical grey Line on my Screen -Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus

This evening I was working and mistakenly pressed the print-screen button, didn't understand if I won't save it would  cause me this issue.

At the moment my screen has this grey vertical line, and my logs are flooded by below messages:

```
Mar 11 23:16:45 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (eog:4704): EOG-WARNING **: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.cache/thumbnails/normal/a01ae0877394f13026ab01f9eae1181c.png': No such file or directory

Mar 11 23:16:46 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (eog:4704): EOG-WARNING **: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.cache/thumbnails/normal/6001204b04afaf0cfeb1eba96f162d83.png': No such file or directory

Mar 11 23:16:46 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (eog:4704): EOG-WARNING **: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.cache/thumbnails/normal/b0b9da5b06593da5ed2f3357d046e539.png': No such file or directory

Mar 11 23:29:35 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (eog:4985): EOG-WARNING **: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.cache/thumbnails/normal/ee3821784782d33725fa45a58d6d55e4.png': No such file or directory

Mar 11 23:35:14 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (nautilus:3134): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/ik/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.

Mar 11 23:35:14 ik0 gnome-session[2943]: (zeitgeist-datahub:3646): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/ik/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/home/ik/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.
```

I tried killing the gnome-screenshot processes by searching it with:

```
ps aux | grep gnome-screenshot
```

as suggested in: [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873813/how-to-get-rid-of-grey-area-after-gnome-screenshot-being-executed/912153) but it results in "No process Found".

Please find attached my screen for viewing the issue:
[image: myscreen]

Also below info on graphics driver from `lshw`:

```
*-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 06
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:28 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Could anyone please help.!

Comment: update:- So I just found out (that connecting a monitor via a VGA doesn't show any grey line on the monitor, however the laptop screen does still reflect the issue. Does it mean my laptop screen has got some hardware issues or what?

Comment: I would like to update all: I am certain that it is a hardware problem now. consider this case is closed.